# Using Invoke-restmethod gives "access to the path <path> is denied

Tags: windows, powershell, invoke-restmethod

I am trying to send a file via multipart formdata via `invoke-restmethod`. I don't have write permmision on the server but type filename works fine
My command is  `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri url -Method Post   -infile  file`

Comment: Does <path> show the path of your infile?

Comment: Yes, the <path> is the path of the file I want to send

Answer (score 0):

Maybe file is not available in the PowerShell if its on a network location or if it is read only.
The read only problem is described here: https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/pwhsw2/invokerestmethod_method_put_infile_doesnt_work/

basically it is changing permissions as PowerShell has bug here:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path <path> -Name IsReadOnly -Value $False
```

Then try again. If you can't change permissions you might switch to PowerShell 7